# How are people recognizing this person from the end of The Mandalorian Episode 9?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, boba-fett

Some minor spoilers ahead. **Fair warning.**

Episode 9 (S2E1) saw our hero return to Tatooine looking for another Mandalorian. Instead we find someone in some familiar green armor trying to pretend to be one (which makes Mando none too happy). Anyways, they strike a compromise to fight a Krayt Dragon and Mando gets the armor back. But the episode ends with someone watching Mando riding off into the distance, and this person turns around to face the camera.

Everyone and their dog is [saying it's Boba Fett](https://www.vulture.com/article/the-mandalorian-season-2-temuera-morrison-boba-fett-jango-fett.html).

The question I have is how were we (the audience) supposed to know it was Fett? The last time we saw him he was kinda being dragged to his presumptive death inside a [sarlacc](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sarlacc), still wearing that armor.

Comment: Somehow his armor made it out of the pit - stands to reason a body would have come along for the ride. I don't know that it's 100% confirmed to be Fett, but it's definitely Temura Morrison who played the clones / Jango Fett. Given that we also know Tano will be in the series as well, it * could * be Capt. Rex, but given the episode's focus on the armor, it's likely indeed Fett. Apparently dead characters have come back from much worse....honestly though, you only * assume * it's Fett and only if you are steeped in the canon. Right now, it's a mystery in terms of this series

Comment: I appreciate the spoiler warnings, but the including boba-fett tag kinda defeats the purpose

Comment: @Nolimon We [had that discussion on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12805/should-a-topic-tag-be-avoided-because-it-might-be-a-spoiler). The tag needs to be there for people looking for the topic

Comment: I mean, the actor matches, and Boba Fett survived the sarlacc in legends, so it's very easy for people to put those together and speculate. We'll probably get a definitive answer next episode, so it kinda feels like this question has an expiration date.

Comment: @Harabeck I'm not asking if he actually *is* Fett. I'm saying others are pretty definitively saying it is. What are they basing that on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though I might be proven wrong, I'll explain what people are basing their theories on.

In *Attack of the Clones*, we saw that the Kaminoans used Jango Fett as a template for their clone army, Jango Fett was played by Kiwi actor Temuera Morrison.

We also got to know that Jango asked for *only one thing, an unaltered clone for himself* that he named Boba, so Boba should be an exact copy of Jango meaning looks like the actor who played Jango no matter what his age is.

Also as others pointed, the Expanded Universe that kept Star Wars alive for a long time, now referred to as legends, notably *A Barve Like That: The Tale of Boba Fett* tells the story of Boba escaping the Sarlacc.

Also to be noted that the Sarlacc does not kill you directly, it will keep you for a long time to be digested so he might have fought his way out. I think future episodes will (should) explain that and that might be proven wrong (he might be a clone trooper or commander), but Boba Fett is an extremely popular character and that's why people are assuming that.

**Update on the answer:** The Mandalorian Chapter 14: The Tragedy (S2E6) confirmed that the character appearing in indeed *Bobba Fett*.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the episode, the sarlacc is dead (makes a convenient hidey hold for a krayt dragon)

Comment: @Machavity I thought it was a different sarlacc.  That did not look like the pit of  Carkoon to me.

Comment: Plus, the armour must have gotten out of the Sarlaac *somehow*.  It's reasonably safe to assume that, dead or alive, Boba Fett's body probably exited at the same time.

Comment: Also, imdb (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11150494/?ref_=ttep_ep1) has credit for boba fett? Of course that may, or may not be authoritative ...

Comment: @L.T.Smash I thought it was a back entrance, or even a side tunnel that the krayt dragon could have made after the sarlacc was out. As soon as they said "abandoned sarlacc pit" my radar was humming for Boba Fett to be alive.

Comment: They are indeed trying to integrate *Legends* character into the mainstream saga once again, as you might remember **Thrawn** was also mentioned in Chapter 13.

Comment: @user10191234 - Thrawn is already well and truly re-integrated into Disney canon via excellent appearances in Star Wars: Rebels and his own new book series

Answer (score 6):

At this point, the audience aren't really meant to *know* it's Fett, although attentive fans have good reason to suspect it and a little out-of-universe knowledge is why so many people are certain.

In canon, we know Boba was a clone of Jango, so anyone played by Temuera Morrison (Jango's actor) could possibly be Boba. We also know that Boba's armour made it out of the sarlacc pit and (if we trust Jabba's threats) that sarlaccs take a millenium to kill, so it's at least plausible that the man himself escaped. He first appears watching Din Djarin just after Din prominently straps the Fett armour to his bike, so storytelling convention suggests he's interested in it.

Outside of canon, Boba Fett's a very popular character and *Star Wars*, like all long-running fiction, loves to resurrect popular characters. In fact, that's exactly what happened in Legends, where he had a long, exciting, and very marketable life after escaping the pit. And Disney are clearly willing to bring back popular or useful bits of Legends, such as Grand Admiral Thrawn or Palpatine's cloning shenanigans.

Finally and entirely outside of fiction, there have been consistent rumours about Morrison playing Fett going back to [at least May of this year](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/mandalorian-finds-boba-fett-temuera-morrison-1293675), building on fan speculation [as early as the first season](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/mandalorian-all-but-iconic-character-has-returned-1260226). In September, [a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsLeaks/comments/ivby95/temuera_morrisons_cv_on_talent_agency_website/) noted that a talent agency's online CV for Morrison listed him as Boba Fett in *The Mandalorian* (it's since been removed).

So the fanbase has been expecting Boba Fett to reappear for a long time, there have been strong indications of it from several sources, and now we have a mystery man who looks a lot like Boba Fett should. I think that's why everyone's so certain, despite the ambiguity of the episode itself.

Comment: excellent reference to the talent agency tidbit - here's a reference describing that - https://www.starwarsnewsnet.com/2020/09/the-mandalorian-another-potential-hint-temuera-morrison-is-returning-to-play-boba-fett-in-season-2.html

Answer (score 0):

He is there on Tatooine, where Boba was last seen. He is watching Mando speed off with Boba's armor. He is played by the same actor who played Jango Fett, a character we know is dead (beheaded) but from whom Boba was cloned. It conceivably might be some other clone of Jango (there were many), but considering where he is, and the implication that he has interest in Mandalorians and their armor, it's clear that the audience is meant to at least think that this is Boba Fett.